# How to add GPS data to metadata on windows phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am making a camera app in C# for Windows Phone 8.1 RT and want to add GPS location to the metadata of the just taken picture.

Reading location data from the GPS is not a problem.
Reading metadata from an (in this case) image.jpg is not a problem.
Writing/editing data however is, because some fields are readonly.

Take picture, then saving:

```
public async void take_picture()
{
    ImageEncodingProperties format = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
    format.Width = resolutionwidth;
    format.Height = resolutionheight;

    var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(format, imageStream);
    //some more code

    StorageFile file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("nameofpicture.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, fileStream);
}
```

Read the metadata. (These properties are now empty, but properties can be read from another picture.)

```
private async void metaread_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file1 = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("nameofpicture.jpg");
    var fileprops = await file1.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
    textblock1.Text = "manufacturer: " + fileprops.CameraManufacturer; //writable property
    textblock2.Text = "model: " + fileprops.CameraModel; //writable property
    textblock3.Text = "title: " + fileprops.Title; //writable property
    textblock4.Text = "latitude: " + fileprops.Latitude; //readonly property
    textblock5.Text = "longtitude: " + fileprops.Longitude; //readonly property
    textblock6.Text = "orientation: " + fileprops.Orientation; //readonly property
}
```

Modify writable metadata:

```
private async void metawrite_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile file2 = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("nameofpicture.jpg");
    var fileprops = await file2.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
    fileprops.Title = "picture by me";
    await fileprops.SavePropertiesAsync();
}
```

Question: how can the readonly properties be set?
The "ImageEncodingProperties" set properties of the image, but not the file.

Comment: So I'm guessing that you are generating the image in some way that does not have the geo data that the camera should be adding ([assuming location is turned on](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp7/pictures/add-location-info-to-my-pictures))?

Comment: Location Services is switched on. I tested this by displaying the coordinates on the screen. The option to save location data with the picture is active. I checked all the option used for creating the image and haven't found any reference to (GPS)location. Unless I missed it ofcourse.  Also the default camera app does save the GPS data with the picture.

Comment: No, I meant specificaly if the settings are on to include location information in photos taken by the camera: "Include location info in pictures you take."

Comment: "Include location info in pictures you take." - yes this is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this one. See RD8388's answer. Just need to convert the lat/long to Degree/Minute/Second format. You do not need to comment out the longitude denominator as he suggested. Just make sure that your the seconds (of numerator property) divided by the denominator falls within the expected range.

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=aaf0b373-b0e0-4d91-84d8-69e768a374d8

Comment: Good to know that EXIF data (in this case GPS) is saved as a part of the image and not the file itself.  Thanks.